# Simple class for 2D <-> 1D array index conversion

Tags: c++, vectors

I made a class to convert the index between 2D and 1D arrays. 
For example, 
between

{1,3,5,7,9,11} and {{1,3},{5,7},{9,11}}

- When `i` is 0, `xy` should be (0,0)
- When `i` is 1, `xy` should be (0,1)
- When `i` is 2, `xy` should be (1,0)

And so on...

I would be able to convert between the `i`-index and the `xy`-index to find get the equivalent location. I feel like this piece of code may be too long for its purpose.

```
class IndexConv {
    public:
    IndexConv(int rows, int cols);
    bool check_i(int i) const;
    bool check_xy(int x, int y) const;
    pair<int, int> to_xy(int i) const;
    int to_i(int x, int y) const;
    private:
    const int rows_;
    const int cols_;
};

IndexConv::IndexConv(int rows, int cols)
    :rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {}

bool IndexConv::check_i(int i) const
{
    return i>=0 || i<rows_*cols_;
}

bool IndexConv::check_xy(int x, int y) const
{
    return x>=0 && y>=0 && x<rows_ && y<cols_;
}
pair<int, int> IndexConv::to_xy(int i) const
{
    if(!check_i(i)) throw out_of_range("IndexConv: i out of bounds.");
    int x = i/cols_;
    int y = i-x*cols_;
    return make_pair(x,y);
}

int IndexConv::to_i(int x, int y) const
{
    if(!check_xy(x,y)) throw out_of_range("IndexConv: xy out of bounds.");
    int i = x*cols_+ y;
    return  i;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Use modulus**

Instead if this `i-x*cols_` you can use the modulus operator `i % cols_`.

**Use a unsigned type.**

If you use unsigned there is no need to check for `x >= 0 && y >= 0`. Also you can con throw the exception directly in check. And you just need `check_xy`.

```
    void IndexConv::check(unsigned x, unsigned y) const
    {
        if(x >= rows_ || y >= cols_) 
            throw std::out_of_range("IndexConv: parameter out of bounds.");
    }

    pair<int, int> IndexConv::to_xy(unsigned i) const
    {
        int x = i / cols_;
        int y = i % cols_;
        check(x, y);
        return make_pair(x, y);
    }

    int IndexConv::to_i(unsigned x, unsigned y) const
    {
        check(x, y);
        return x * cols_ + y;
    }
```

EDIT: Changed the answer to keep check_xy. Keeping `check_i` can map `(0,2)` to `2` when it should throw an exception (Following your example).

Comment: Do you still need to return true in the check function?

Comment: no that's a mistake, edited.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent suggestions by @MAG, I suggest the following:

**A better class name**

I suggest using a full name rather than a shorter name - `IndexConverter`.

**No need to use `const` in member variables**

I don't see any benefit of using `const` member variables. You can simply use (I am incorporating the suggestion to use an unsigned type):

```
unsigned int rows_;
unsigned int cols_;
```

**Define a size type**

To further enhance consistency in the class, define a size type in your class and use it.

```
class IndexConverter
{
   public:

      using size_type = unsigned int;

      IndexConverter(size_type rows, size_type cols);
      bool check_i(size_type i) const;
      bool check_xy(size_type x, size_type y) const;
      pair<size_type, size_type> to_xy(size_type i) const;
      size_type to_i(size_type x, size_type y) const;
   private:
      size_type rows_;
      size_type cols_;
};
```

This allows you to change the type used for size with minimal disruption.

**Use `std::pair` instead of `pair`**

Your use of

```
pair<int, int> to_xy(int i) const;
```

works presumably because you have added

```
using namespace std;
```

in the .h file before the definition of the class. See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Remove the `using` line and use `std::pair`.

**Better names for `to_i` and `to_xy`**

I would suggest using `to_1d_index` and `to_2d_index` instead.

In the same vein, I would suggest using `check_1d_index` and `check_2d_index`. If you follow the suggestion by @MAG, then you need just `check_2d_index`.

**Add an overload of `to_1d_index`**

```
      size_type to_1d_index(std::pair<size_type, size_type> xy) const;
```

This is a convenience so that you can use something like:

```
IndexConverter c(10, 20);
unsigned int i = 2;
auto 2d_index = c.to_2d_index(i);
auto j = c.to_1d_index(2d_index);
```

and expect to see `j == i`.

**Adding whitespaces**

Adding a blank line between function declarations makes it easier to read. That could be my personal taste! YMMV.

**Final Suggested Version**

```
class IndexConverter
{
   public:

      using size_type = unsigned it;

      IndexConverter(size_type rows, size_type cols);

      void check_2d_index(size_type x, size_type y) const;

      std::pair<size_type, size_type> to_2d_index(size_type i) const;

      size_type to_1d_index(size_type x, size_type y) const;

      size_type to_1d_index(std::pair<size_type, size_type> xy) const;

   private:
      size_type rows_;
      size_type cols_;
};
```